# MySQL count as a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure

```
leads
-id
-fname
-lname


subcontractors
-id
-leads_id
-fname
-lname
-status
```

Leads can have many `subcontractors`. The `subcontractors.status` tells if the subcontractor if active or suspended

Question is how do I select leads with a count column the tells how many active and suspended subcons they have?

I have this right now:

```
SELECT 
l.id, 
l.fname, 
l.lname, 
s.status 
FROM leads l 
INNER JOIN subcontractors s 
ON l.id = s.leads_id 
GROUP BY l.id ORDER BY l.id DESC;
```

My goal is to have something like this

```
id | fname | lname | active_subcon_count | suspended_subcon_count
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use condition aggregate function `COUNT` with `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT 
    l.id, 
    l.fname, 
    l.lname, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 'active' THEN 1 END) ,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN s.status = 'suspended' THEN 1 END) 
from leads l 
INNER JOIN subcontractors s 
ON l.id = s.leads_id 
GROUP BY l.id , l.fname, l.lname
ORDER BY l.id DESC;
```

or mysql can do `SUM` like this.

```
SELECT 
    l.id, 
    l.fname, 
    l.lname, 
    SUM(s.status = 'active') active_subcon_count ,
    SUM(s.status = 'suspended') suspended_subcon_count 
from leads l 
INNER JOIN subcontractors s 
ON l.id = s.leads_id 
GROUP BY l.id , l.fname, l.lname
ORDER BY l.id DESC;
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks, Will select this as answer

Comment: Are you sure about the 2nd query? Never used the syntax before, tried and it does not work on my MySQL 5.7. It returns the same value as `COUNT(*)`. `COUNT(CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 END)` or `COUNT(IF(expr, 1, NULL))` inside works as expected.

Comment: @fifonik Thank for point out I forgot to modify `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.